# How to get automatic notification when user uploaded file in the database has gone above 15 days? I'm currently working with asp.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a web application for my university ..by which students can fill forms user information and form after converting to .pdf format will be saved in the database and through smtp server this form will be sent to management for further processing. Now the question is is there any way to send notification to management if the for being sent to management has not got the consideration(reject/accept) for above 15 days?

Answer (score 0):

You host your application on IIS. [IIS restarts pool every 1740 minutes](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/why-is-the-iis-default-app-pool-recycle-set-to-1740-minutes).

Just put in `Global.ajax.cs` in `Application_Start` method all logic you need. I mean get list of your files that should be notify and send email.